# ImageView in UITableViewCell won't display

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, storyboard

I've put an ImageView in a UITableViewCell on my Storyboard but at run time it is not showing up on my simulator. How do I solve this?

My storyboard:

[image: Image of my storyboard]
The object overview of my storyboard:

[image]
The Swift code that fills up the cells:

```
func tableView(gamesListTableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = gamesListTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Game", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
    if (indexPath.row < GamesList.count) {
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = GamesList[indexPath.row]["game_guid"].string!;
        cell.textLabel?.text = GamesList[indexPath.row]["opponent_name"].string!;
        if (GamesList[indexPath.row]["self_turn"] == false) {
            cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.greenColor();
        } else if (GamesList[indexPath.row]["game_idle_time"] <= 60) {
            cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.yellowColor();
        } else {
            cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.redColor();
        }
    } else {
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = InvitesList[indexPath.row - GamesList.count]["invite_guid"].string!;
        cell.textLabel?.text = InvitesList[indexPath.row - GamesList.count]["invite_text"].string!;
        cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.blueColor();
    }
    return cell
}
```

What it looks like at runtime:

[image]

Comment: You should probably pause the execution and view your view hierarchy in Xcode. Check what the frame size it at run time and see if A.) something is overlapping it or B.)If your constraints are wrong.

Comment: You're right. It is showing up but it's off the view. That is because the view above of ImageView (the ContentView) is too wide. How do I narrow this down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably pause the execution and view your view hierarchy in Xcode. Check what the frame size it at run time and see if A.) something is overlapping it or B.)If your constraints are wrong.

Comment: I can't seem to find out how to pause the execution and view the view hierarchy in Xcode. Can you point me towards the right direction?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-debugger/using_view_debugger/using_view_debugger.html